# language subsite in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, globalization

So we have a site that was made quite some time ago. It uses asp 2.0. Currently the site is not multilingual. Since this site was not created with multi langue in mind it contains a lot of images with text on them.

Some time ago a college went ahead to create 3 versions of the site by basically copying the whole site and translating each one. I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it.

I would now like to go ahead and merge those sites. To create something like www.site.com/en/ for English for example.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Can I just take the main site and create for example 2 langue buttons and subfolders containing the translated versions? or is this more complex?

I should note that the site is using a masterpage.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globalization of an application is huge topic. You could start reading this guide:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688110.aspx

Basically, you have to:

- refactor your code to put strings in resource files
- refactor your images to use text from resource files and backgrounds (css will help)

Then you have to translate the resource files and put them in the application.

Then you can use the Routes to set the language in the URL using a route like this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("PageId", "{language}/MyPage", "~/MyPage.aspx");
```

Comment: I will have a look at this. I though it was a quick implementation but it seams to be more difficult then i had thought. Thank you for the information.